# can't run zookeeper while 2181 port is already use in apache druid

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, druid

hello iam beginner in druid and kafka. i run kafka server and druid server at same localhost

i have ran zookeeper in kafka by following `./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` and ran kafka server by following `./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`.

I try to connect kafka server to druid server for inputing data. When i try to run zookeeper of druid by following documentation of druid `./bin/start-micro-quickstart` the result say "cannot start up because port 2181 is already use" and then i researched about this error that i have tried to change the port by set up the "zoo.cfg" file under "conf" directory on druid. I have changed the port into 2080 and etc.

When i try to run it again by `./bin/start-micro-quickstart` the result still the same "cannot start up because port 2181 is already use"

How to change the port correctly?
Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
 export DRUID_SKIP_PORT_CHECK=1
```

https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/167c45260c76057b9856bd073661365663bd80f2/examples/bin/verify-default-ports#L41

You could also use same zookeeper for both use cases

./bin/start-micro-quickstart is running the verify for specific port 2181,

https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/ce1faa56352766522610e3ae306c15b55df19fb0/examples/conf/supervise/single-server/micro-quickstart.conf#L2

if you changed the default port you need to remove / edit the verification, the suggestion in your link ( https://www.druidforum.org/t/druid-port/4805/19 ) is to remove the druid from starting its zookeeper, if thats what you want you can edit what they suggest and go with it

https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/master/examples/conf/supervise/single-server/micro-quickstart.conf

Further suggestion , The druid is using zookeeper with root path /druid , you can set kafka to work with root path /kafka and they both will use same zookeeper ,

Comment: i have tried using that script. But when i ran ./bin/start-micro-quickstart again. The result say failed zk. My case as same as this case https://www.druidforum.org/t/druid-port/4805/19 but i get nothing

Comment: ./bin/start-micro-quickstart  is running the verify for specific port 2181, if you changed the default port you need to remove / edit the verification,  the suggestion in your link is to remove the druid from starting its zookeeper, if thats what you want you can edit what they suggest and go with it

Comment: Kafka is starting its own zookeeper which is also using the standard port 2181. If you skip the port check, Druid will still not be able to bring up its own Zookeeper. So, changing the port was the right thing to do.

Comment: Kafka is not starting zookeeper by itself

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `zookeeper-server-start.sh` if you already have a running Zookeeper on port 2181

You may need to modify `zookeeper.connect` in `server.properties` to point at a different Zookeeper host:port or chroot